# Converting numeric String to List of Int in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to convert a string (of numbers) into individual digits. There are multiple ways to solve this, one being to `map digitToInt "1234"`

I was trying a similar approach but instead of using `digitToInt`, I was trying to use the `read::Char->Int` function. However I am getting compilation error when I use the above, as in:

```
map (read::Char->Int) ['1','2']
```

gives me the following error given below. I am not sure what is wrong here, I am trying to map a function which takes Char over a list of Char, what am I missing?

Please do not tell me of alternate approach as I understand there are several other ways to do this. Just want to understand what is happening here.

```
Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: Char -> Int
        Actual type: String -> Int
    • In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(read :: Char -> Int)’
```

Comment: There is no function `read::Char->Int` in the default libraries. `read` is only defined for string input in Prelude. You can always look at the type definitions at haskell.org/hoogle

Comment: The module Data.Char provides the function [`digitToInt :: Char -> Int`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Char+-%3E+Int).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is `read :: Read a => String -> a`. So `read` should be applied to `String` not to `Char`. Try this instead:

```
 map (read :: String -> Int) ["1", "2"]
 -- or
 map read ["1", "2"] :: [Int] -- same but clearer?
```

Comment: ahh completely forgot that read can only take string as the input! Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

[`read :: Read a => String -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read) converts a *string* to a `Read`able element. So if you want to read the digits from a string, you can use:

```
map (read . pure :: Char -> Int) ['1','2']
```

but if the characters are digits, it might be better to use the [**`digitToInt :: Char -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:digitToInt) function:

```
import Data.Char(digitToInt)

map digitToInt ['1', '2']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try doing it this way `map (\x -> read (x:[]) :: Int) "12"`
This should work, if you have any doubts about it just search lambda expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like that:

```
toInt x = read x :: Int
map (toInt . (:"")) ['1', '2']
```